# Is it possible to use WatchConnectivity in background

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchconnectivity

I have an watchOS app that used WatchConnectivity framework to open an URL in Safari. When my app is running on the iPhone and running on the Apple Watch at the same time, pressing the open URL button on the Apple Watch app does launch Safari on the iPhone as what I've implemented using WCSessionDelegate. But this won't work if the iPhone app is not running. Is there a way to launch the URL on iPhone when pressing the button on the Apple Watch even if the iPhone app is not active? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you need to use Handoff for something like this?

Answer (score 4):

Using the WatchConnectivity's `sendMessage` API the watch app is able to get the phone to launch your iOS app in the background, but a background running iOS app won't be able to open the URL resulting in Safari being launched.

Answer (score 2):

No, Apple does not allow you to start an iPhone app from the watch (although a lot of developers seem to want this functionality.)  You can always enter an enhancement bug request.